# What could be the reason that PHP isn't outputting video?

Tags: php, html, video, ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to create a PHP file in which it can output a video that is not under public_html. I have been using the following PHP script to output video:

```
<?php

//PHP script to output videos

//Full version of file does a lot of database stuff

//Get $path of file

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size

$contents = file_get_contents($path);
echo $contents;
//I also tried readfile($path) with the same results
```

I have a suspicion that it is my server. So, I tried to view the same video file directly (www.site.com/video.mp4). Doing it directly worked fine.

Originally, this worked fine. It wasn't until just recently that it doesn't work. I'm not sure if it's something I installed on my server. I remember doing a few changes to the php.ini and maybe .htaccess (or some other hidden with settings inside them) which makes me think it has something to do with that. Is there something within php.ini and/or .htaccess (or any other hidden settings file similar to php.ini and .htaccess) that I would need to change?

Right now, I just testing my site on desktop browsers. I've tested this on both Chrome and Firefox and they give me the same results. I've tried using ffmpeg to convert my videos to many different video formats, but it comes out with the same results (can play directly, can't play through php script).

When I open the php file, the console has no errors.

What could be a reason that my PHP script is not outputting the video content?

Comment: What does the script do? Does it output anything? Is there an entry in error_log?

Comment: @Vero it outputs video. and nope, no errors.

Comment: Is it sending the correct `Content-Length`?

Comment: @Barmar im pretty sure it is. im passing it through the function `filesize()` with the right $path.

Comment: memory issues?  read few bytes and flush them in a loop?

Comment: @Sunand how do i do that?

Comment: @RobAveryIV I mean when you view what's being sent to the browser, does it show the content length that you expect?

Comment: @Sunand yeah. for debugging purposes, i echo'd what `filesize($path)` gives, and it is correct.

Comment: try adding `AddType video/mp4 .mp4` to the htaccess file.

Comment: @bitWorking once I do, do i need to restart the server?

Comment: no, you don't have to restart..

Comment: @bitWorking that did not work

Comment: yes..I realized that it's nonsense..you already output the content type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61608/discussion-between-rob-avery-iv-and-bitworking).

Comment: @RobAveryIV `readfile()` can and will work just fine.  You probably have some sort of permissions error, but without seeing the error log output, it's anyone's guess.  `readfile()` is what you want (assuming your server doesn't support a sendfile function with response headers, which would be faster).  Also, be sure to be careful on how you're setting your path.  Don't let folks download any file off your filesystem that they want.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code copied from php fread site it has these befits as he mentioned

```
 if ($file = fopen($path, 'rb')) {
    while(!feof($file) and (connection_status()==0)) {
      print(fread($file, 1024*8));
      flush();
    }
    fclose($file);
  }
```

- Works with large files, and uses only an 8KB buffer per transfer.
- Stops transferring if the client is disconnected (unlike many scripts, that continue to read and buffer the entire file, wasting valuable resources) but does not halt the script
- Returns TRUE if transfer was completed, or FALSE if the client was disconnected before completing the download - you'll often need this, so you can log downloads correctly.
- Sends a number of headers, including ones that ensure it's cached for a maximum of 2 hours on any browser/proxy, and "Content-Length" which most people seem to forget.

https://php.net/fread

Comment: Though, using Chrome dev tools, in the Network tab, I see that it is loading a video. Slowly, it receives the 4MB video file (at least the response is 4MB and it says its type is video/mp4).

Comment: This is horribly inefficient.  Use `readfile()`.  Also, this does not necessarily stop transferring if a client disconnects... that's dependent upon PHP and web server configuration.  And, your code snippet has no mention of caching or content-length headers at all.